# How to compile SWC in FDT without including the SDK libraries?

Tags: flash, fdt, compc

It seems the command -el forces external linkages but then it won't compile because options from playerglobal.swc cannot be found.  I just want to build a swc from the source folder and not include any external assets.

My second question is about building FAT SWC files including the ASDOC information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how todo it in ANT.

```
<target name="foundation build-debug">
    <delete file="${FDTProjectPath}/bin/${foundation-debug-file}"/>
    <fdt.loadProjectProperties projectname="frameworks" />
    <fdt.launch.library projectname="${FDTProject}" debug="true" autoaddclasspath="false" compilerarguments="
        -target-player=${FDTProjectPlayerVersion}
        -include-sources=${FDTProjectPath}/src
        -allow-source-path-overlap=true 
            -external-library-path+=${FDTProjectSdkPath}/frameworks/libs/ 
            -external-library-path+=${FDTProjectPath}/lib 
        -incremental=true 
        -benchmark=true" target="${FDTProjectPath}/bin/${foundation-debug-file}" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have each SDK .SWC set to 'Use as Runtime Shared Code'. This is located in your project's properties page.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't sure if that functioned as identifier for RSLs or not.  It should say Use as External Shared Code

Comment: this doesn't resolve my issue. when I try to execute the swf i get:  Class spark.components::Application could not be found. and It doesn't try to find the spark components that i have on that same location

Comment: @ufk What are you tying to do? This thread is about excluding classes from SWCs. The error you're getting is what someone wants when they don't want to include definitions like 'spark.components::Application'